# Powershell window wont stay open for start-process enter-pssession in new window

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have this command that works but the window wont stay open. I need this to open in a new window and not in the initial window. Is there anyway to get this to not close after it establishes a PS Session?

```
start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList { Enter-PSSession -ComputerName my_computer -Credential USER -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like powershell.exe needed the -noexit option.  It wasn't working even without start-process.  Notice you have to quote it or else it looks like a start-process parameter.

```
start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-noexit',{ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName my_computer -Credential USER -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile)}
```

Comment: Background info on the "quirky" behavior of `Enter-PSSession` in scripting and CLI scenarios, which, unfortunately, won't change: [GitHub issue #16350](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16350)